# Title Name not showing and background color not changing

Tags: c++, class, winapi, polymorphism

I have code for a C++ Win32 Wrapper Class which i am fiddling with. Since I'm just trying to use handler's, i removed the WindowProcedure and just used a message router. And somehow things are getting buggy.
Now with just the message router the title of the WindowClass which i have tired to make doesn't display the title name of the window.
And somehow i can't seem to get the background color to change.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "BaseWindow.h"
#include "GameWindow.h"

    int APIENTRY WinMain ( HINSTANCE h_instance, HINSTANCE h_prev_instance, LPSTR lp_cmd_line, int n_cmd_show ) {
        // Create the Game Window
        GameWindow game_window ( h_instance, TEXT ( "GameWindow" ) );
        game_window.Register ();

        // Create the Base Window
        BaseWindow base_window ( TEXT ( "BaseWindow" ), game_window.ClassName () );
        base_window.Create ();
        base_window.Show ();

        // Pump Messages
        MSG messages;
        int status;
        while ( ( status = GetMessage ( &messages, 0, 0, 0 ) ) != 0 ) {
            if ( status == -1 ) {
                // Break;
                break;
            }
            TranslateMessage ( &messages );
            DispatchMessage ( &messages );
        }
        return messages.wParam;

    }
```

**AbstractWindow.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __ABSTRACT_WINDOW_H__
#define __ABSTRACT_WINDOW_H__

#include <Windows.h>

class AbstractWindow {
    public:
        AbstractWindow ();
        ~AbstractWindow ();

        virtual bool Create ();

        static LRESULT CALLBACK MessageRouter ( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );

    protected:
        HWND hwnd_;

        DWORD style_ex_;
        LPCTSTR class_name_;
        LPCTSTR window_name_;
        DWORD style_;
        int x_;
        int y_;
        int width_;
        int height_;
        HWND parent_;
        HMENU menu_;
        HINSTANCE h_instance_;
        LPVOID param_;

        // Default Handlers
        virtual bool OnCreate ( HWND ) = 0;
        virtual bool OnCommand ( int, int ) = 0;
        virtual bool OnDestroy () = 0;

        virtual bool EraseBackground ( HWND, WPARAM ) = 0;
        virtual bool LeftButtonUp () = 0;

};
#endif // !__ABSTRACT_WINDOW_H__
```

**AbstractWindow.cpp**

```
#include "AbstractWindow.h"

AbstractWindow::AbstractWindow () {}

AbstractWindow::~AbstractWindow () {}

bool AbstractWindow::Create () {
    hwnd_ = CreateWindowEx (
        style_ex_,
        class_name_,
        window_name_,
        style_,
        x_,
        y_,
        width_,
        height_,
        parent_,
        menu_,
        h_instance_,
        this                    // Pointer to this class instance
        );

    return ( !hwnd_ ? false : true );
}

LRESULT CALLBACK AbstractWindow::MessageRouter ( HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param ) {
    AbstractWindow* abstract_window = 0;

    if ( message == WM_NCCREATE ) {
        abstract_window = ( AbstractWindow* ) ( ( LPCREATESTRUCT ( l_param ) )->lpCreateParams );
        SetWindowLong ( hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, long ( abstract_window ) );
        abstract_window->OnCreate ( hwnd );
    }
    else {
        abstract_window = ( AbstractWindow* ) ( GetWindowLong ( hwnd, GWL_USERDATA ) );

        if ( abstract_window ) {
            switch ( message ) {
                case WM_COMMAND:
                    return abstract_window->OnCommand ( LOWORD ( w_param ), HIWORD ( w_param ) );
                case WM_DESTROY:
                    return abstract_window->OnDestroy ();

                case WM_ERASEBKGND:
                    return abstract_window->EraseBackground ( hwnd, w_param );
                case WM_LBUTTONUP:
                    return abstract_window->LeftButtonUp ();

                default:
                    return DefWindowProc ( hwnd, message, w_param, l_param );
            }
        }
        else {
            return DefWindowProc ( hwnd, message, w_param, l_param );
        }

    }
}
```

**BaseWindow.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __BASE_WINDOW_H__
#define __BASE_WINDOW_H__

#include <Windows.h>
#include "AbstractWindow.h"

class BaseWindow : public AbstractWindow {
    public:
        BaseWindow ();
        ~BaseWindow ();

        BaseWindow ( const TCHAR*, const TCHAR* );

        // Display the window onto the screen while updating the client area
        void Show ();


    private:
        virtual bool OnCreate ( HWND );
        virtual bool OnCommand ( int, int );
        virtual bool OnDestroy ();

        virtual bool EraseBackground ( HWND, WPARAM );
        virtual bool LeftButtonUp ();


};
#endif // !__BASE_WINDOW_H__
```

**BaseWindow.cpp**

```
#include "BaseWindow.h"

BaseWindow::BaseWindow () {}

BaseWindow::~BaseWindow () {}

BaseWindow::BaseWindow ( const TCHAR* window_name, const TCHAR* class_name ) : AbstractWindow () {
    // Member variables are declaried in AbstractWindow as Protected
    window_name_ = window_name;
    class_name_ = class_name;

    // Get the module handle for the window currently running
    h_instance_ = GetModuleHandle ( NULL );
    style_ = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE;
    x_ = CW_USEDEFAULT;
    y_ = CW_USEDEFAULT;
    width_ = CW_USEDEFAULT;
    height_ = CW_USEDEFAULT;
    parent_ = NULL;
    menu_ = NULL;

}

void BaseWindow::Show () {
    // hwnd_ is from AbstractWindow Class
    ShowWindow ( hwnd_, SW_SHOW );
    UpdateWindow ( hwnd_ );
}


// Handlers

bool BaseWindow::OnCreate (HWND hwnd) {
    MessageBox ( hwnd, TEXT ( "[BaseWindow] Window has been successfully created!" ), TEXT ( "SUCCESS" ), MB_OK );

    return true;
}

bool BaseWindow::OnCommand ( int ctrl_id, int notify_code ) {

    // Lower 16 bits specifies the element the mouse was used on
    // Upper 16 bits specifies the mouse properties
    // ctrl_id = Lower
    // notify_code = Upper
    return true;
}

bool BaseWindow::OnDestroy () {
    PostQuitMessage ( 0 );
    return true;
}

bool BaseWindow::EraseBackground ( HWND hwnd, WPARAM w_param) {
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect ( hwnd, &rect );

    FillRect ( ( HDC ) w_param, &rect, GetSysColorBrush ( COLOR_BTNFACE ) );

    return true;
}

bool BaseWindow::LeftButtonUp () {

    return true;
}
```

**GameWindow.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __GAME_WINDOW_H__
#define __GAME_WINDOW_H__

#include <Windows.h>
#include "AbstractWindow.h"

class GameWindow : protected WNDCLASSEX {
    public:
        GameWindow ();
        ~GameWindow ();

        GameWindow ( HINSTANCE, const TCHAR* );

        virtual bool Register ();

        virtual const TCHAR* ClassName () const;

    protected:
        UINT cb_size_;
        UINT style_;
        WNDPROC lpfn_wnd_proc_;
        int cb_cls_extra_;
        int cb_wnd_extra_;
        HINSTANCE h_instance_;
        HICON h_icon_;
        HCURSOR h_cursor_;
        HBRUSH hbr_background_;
        LPCTSTR lpsz_menu_name_;
        LPCTSTR lpsz_class_name_;
        HICON h_icon_sm_;


};
#endif // !__GAME_WINDOW_H__
```

**GameWindow.cpp**

```
#include "GameWindow.h"

GameWindow::GameWindow () {}

GameWindow::~GameWindow () {}

GameWindow::GameWindow ( HINSTANCE h_instance, const TCHAR* class_name ) {

    // All messages belonging to this Window Class will get sent to MsgRouter

    hInstance =                 h_instance;
    lpszClassName =             class_name;

    lpfnWndProc =               AbstractWindow::MessageRouter;
    lpszMenuName =              NULL;
    cbSize =                    sizeof ( WNDCLASSEX );
    cbClsExtra =                NULL;
    cbWndExtra =                NULL;
    style =                     CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    hIcon =                     LoadIcon ( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
    hIconSm =                   LoadIcon ( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
    hCursor =                   LoadCursor ( NULL, IDC_HAND );
    hbrBackground =             ( HBRUSH ) GetStockObject ( COLOR_BTNFACE );

}

const TCHAR* GameWindow::ClassName () const {
    return lpszClassName;
}

bool GameWindow::Register () {
    return ( ( RegisterClassEx ( this ) ) ? true : false );
}
```

Comment: That's far from a [MCVE] you are required to post for such questions!

Comment: Was removing the window procedure your idea, or did you see that used somewhere?  I'm trying to understand _why_ you want to do it that way.  Also try reducing the code here to the smallest amount required to reproduce the problem.  I don't think you're going to find many people with the patience to go through 7 code files looking for errors.

Comment: Umm . . do you suggest me to add back the Window Procedure ? If not do you know what the rough problem might be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MessageRouter` is missing default processing. Add `DefWindowProc` as shown

```
LRESULT CALLBACK AbstractWindow::MessageRouter ( HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param ) {
    AbstractWindow* abstract_window = 0;

    if ( message == WM_NCCREATE ) {
        abstract_window = ( AbstractWindow* ) ( ( LPCREATESTRUCT ( l_param ) )->lpCreateParams );
        SetWindowLong ( hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, long ( abstract_window ) );
        abstract_window->OnCreate ( hwnd );
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, w_param, l_param);//ADD THIS LINE
    }
    ...
```

For background, you can either handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` or you can set `hbrBackground`

Method 1: handle `WM_ERASEBKGND`

```
virtual LRESULT EraseBackground(HWND hwnd, WPARAM w_param)
{
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
    FillRect((HDC)w_param, &rect, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BTNFACE));
    return 1;
}
```

Method 2: set `hbrBackground` and let window do the rest

```
hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);

virtual LRESULT EraseBackground(HWND hwnd, WPARAM w_param)
{
    //let window do this
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, WM_ERASEBKGND, w_param, 0);
}
```

.........
Edit #2

```
class AbstractWindow
{
    virtual void OnPaint()=0;
    ...
};

AbstractWindow::MessageRouter()
{
case WM_PAINT:
    abstract_window->OnPaint();
    return 0;
...
}

void GameWindow::OnPaint()
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps; 
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps); 
    TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, "Hello, Windows!", 15); 
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps); 
}
```

Comment: Cheers man that did work. I also another problem which i stated in my question. That is, I have problems changing the background color ? How may i fix that ?

Comment: You meaning changing the GameWindow.cpp hbrBackground variable ? I tried that and the background color doesn't change

Comment: JekasG, I got confused. `WM_ERASEBKGND` handler looks fine, I edited some of my comments. What problem do you see? You can either set `hbrBackground ` or you can handle it in `WM_ERASEBKGND`, both should be okay.

Comment: Okay so let me get myself clear. What i want to do is the change the window background color to some other color. Currently it is white. So what happen is ive changed the line hbrBackground = ( HBRUSH ) GetStockObject ( COLOR_BTNFACE ); to hbrBackground =    ( HBRUSH ) ( COLOR_BTNFACE +1); and i have removed the WM_ERASEBKGND from AbstractWindow.cpp and the

Comment: Never mind it works. But i have question. When i try to place it in the WM_LBUTTONUP case why doesnt it work ?

Comment: Actually it doesn't work unless i place abstract_window->EraseBackground ( hwnd, w_param ); into the default case and leaving the WM_LBUTTONUP and it would draw the line when i press my left mouse button

Comment: You are making this very difficult for yourself. You should make a simple WinApi program (Visual Studio will do it for you) and work out all the messages. Plenty of tutorial is available for simple WinApi programs. This framework you are using is very difficult and not very good. Painting is done in `WM_PAINT`. If you want to make paint-brush type program that's a different topic.

Comment: So you think this wrapper class is designed badly ?

Comment: I shouldn't really give opinion about this class, that's subjective. However, for beginners it would be much easier to start with plain Windows API programming. Once you are comfortable with WinApi messages, then you can go to next step which is this or other wrapper classes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Umm I currently have everything working right now. And i want to add bitmaps. I believe i shouldnt be asking this here but i didnt think it was reasonable to post the new question with the new updated code. So i decided to ask here. Umm so i want to add Bitmap in my implementation. I tried to have it called in the OnCreate() Function. Where the the RECT, HDC and HBITMAP is a member variable of AbstractWindow. And for some reason the GetClientRect isn't returning a valid rect dimension from OnCreate but it works in WM_Paint. Any suggestions ?

Comment: No, you have to ask one question and check the box for accept answer when there is answer, I will get points in return. Second, you haven't got very far except make blank window with title and background. You can do the same thing in 2 minutes using plain Windows API. Third, there is lots of WinApi code for loading and painting bitmap. You hold yourself back by not knowing the standard API programming. Lastly, when you ask a new question it gets seen by more people, just make sure it's simplified to standard API so everybody can understand it quickly.

Comment: Well then is there anyway i can optimize my MessageRouter function ?

Comment: `MessageRouter` needs to handle [WM_PAINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so you have to declare `virtual void OnPaint()=0` in `AbstractWindow` class, then declare and define `OnPaint` in `GameWindow` class. Finally in `GameWindow::OnPaint` you obtain HDC, call `HDC hdc = BeginPaint` and paint with `hdc`, end with `EndPaint`